# is it possible Windows privilege escalation using freesshd keys?

Tags: penetration-test, ssh, windows-permissions, oscp

I have unprivileged shell one system.By browsing all folder i found freeSSHD folder

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\freeSSHd

09/26/2008  02:07 PM    <DIR>          .
09/26/2008  02:07 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/26/2008  02:02 PM               668 DSAKey.cfg
09/26/2008  02:02 PM                49 FreeSSHd Website.url
08/21/2008  01:45 PM           856,064 FreeSSHDService.exe
02/28/2011  02:26 AM             1,107 FreeSSHDService.ini
09/26/2008  02:06 PM               395 root
09/26/2008  02:02 PM               887 RSAKey.cfg
09/26/2008  02:02 PM             4,180 unins000.dat
09/26/2008  02:02 PM           695,578 unins000.exe
               8 File(s)      1,558,928 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,289,207,808 bytes free
```

Can any one suggest any way, helpfull to get privileged shell.
Btw Its a windows system
One more point from that ini file i have root password

Comment: To get a privileged shell not with SSH though, this works on Win7/vista and below: Custom Metasploit payload with UAC bypass http://security.stackexchange.com/q/93499/77653 however on win7/xp a pop up asks for process escalation on the target due to UAC protection on win7/vista.